# Comparing rows to identify matches and mismatches

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with 10000+ rows, but the data came from 2 sources, so duplicates exist for the same combination of unique keys. So let's say that columns A and B are the unique identifier. Columns C to K have data about the item specified by the unique key. I need to check if there is a second occurrence of the unique key combination and if so, are the data in columns C to K in the second occurrence the same as in the first occurrence. If they are the same, then copy the row to sheet 2.

> if a1 = a2 and b1 = b2 then check if c1:k1 equals c2:k2 -> copy to sheet 2

I need to create separate lists of matches and mismatches.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using vlookup? When you do this in both directions, you know what the differences are between the two lists. When doing this, make sure that things like spaces are exactly the same. Try using trim on both lists first to remove extra spaces.